# Tkinter - how to pull error messages from cmd on screen?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, permission-denied

I created a .exe file from my .py project. And when I try to save and output the .csv file on the desktop I get 'error 13 permission denied', because I have no admin privileges. Instead, I need to save a file to C:/Users/Public to make it work.
So, how do I make a pop-up window with this message using Tkinter, every time when I get 'error 13'? The error is shown in cmd only.

```
## Write output to csv file
def save_file():
    path_to_output_file = fd.asksaveasfilename()
    if not path_to_output_file:
        return
    file_count = 1
    for rows in range(len(df)):
        if rows % 500 == 0:
            df[rows:rows+500].to_csv(path_to_output_file + str(file_count) + '.csv', index=False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            file_count += 1
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? What is the full error message? You should be able to wrap the offending line in a `try: <line with error> except PermissionError: <code to display popup>`.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__

  File "Directory Master.py", line 136, in save_file

  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 3466, in to_csv

  File "pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1105, in to_csv

  File "pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 237, in save

  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 702, in get_handle

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Melleo/Desktop/dm1.csv'

Comment: It's line 136, which is:
`df[rows:rows+500].to_csv(path_to_output_file + str(file_count) + '.csv', index=False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already got the error message, you can use `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo` function to create a pop-up window and show the error message.
You can find the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
It worked!

```
try:
    df[rows:rows+500].to_csv(path_to_output_file + str(file_count) + '.csv', index=False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
except PermissionError:
    messagebox.showinfo('Can\'t save a file', f'File can\'t be saved to {path_to_output_file} as you don\'t have admin privileges.\nYou need to save a file to \'C:/Users/Public\'')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5soB.jpg)